# How to fetch a relationship collection on a group by statement in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my `buyer_zips` table,

```
id
zip_id
buyer_id
```

`buyer_id` represents `id` of `buyers` table. A buyer can have multiple buyer_zips.

First I wanna fetch data from buyer_zips table along with the count grouped by `zip_id`,

```
BuyerZip::selectRaw('zip_id, count(*) as count')
  ->groupBy('zip_id')->get();
```

Now how do I fetch all the buyers for those zip ids?

Comment: Do you have a relationship set up in `BuyerZip` model for the `Buyer` model?

Comment: A buyer can have multiple buyer_zips. Edited the question.